# Default the column value to the result of a query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve the following

```
create table foo(
    bar int not null default (select default_bar from bars)
)
```

which of course results in an error. Is there any way to derive the default column value from the **result of a query**, *without* using triggers?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use triggers?

Comment: Because I already know I can do it with triggers, just seeing if it's possible without.

Comment: Noway. Only constants and deterministic functions may be used in DEFAULT value (and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html says:

> Expression default values must adhere to the following rules.  An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.
>
> ...
>
> - Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and loadable
>   functions are not permitted.

Read the documentation page for more details. It might answer other questions you have.